# Selecting data from one dataframe base on column in second dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, conditional-statements, selection

I have a dataframe (df), contains datetime columns startdate, enddate and volume of product

If I want to look at one particular date that fit in between startdate and enddate and its total volume, i can do it with no problem at all (see code).

However if I create a second dataframe (call it report), create a list of date that I would like to look at the total volume of product from first df, I came up with an error:

> Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

I read up on things like dropping index on the second df or sorting dates but they don't seem to work

So my working code for requesting volume fitted within startdate and enddate, say first of july 2019:

```
    df[(df['StartDate'] >= '2019-07-01') & (df['EndDate'] <= '2019-10-31')]['Volume'].sum()
```

but if i create a second df (report):

```
    report = pd.Series(pd.date_range('today', periods=len(df), freq='D').normalize(),name='Date')

    report = pd.DataFrame(report)
```

and request what i want to see:

```
    report['trial'] = df[(df['StartDate'] >= report.Date) & (df['EndDate'] <= report.Date)]['Volume'].sum()
```

got this error: 'Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'

Any advice/suggestions welcome, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding `report` as a df column and then comparing with this colum?

Comment: Can you give examples of the data from both DataFrame so we can check the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, some sample data:

```
np.random.seed(42)
dates = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-12-01', freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'StartDate': dates,
    'EndDate': dates + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(),
    'Volume': np.random.randint(1, 10, len(dates))
})

    StartDate    EndDate  Volume
0  2019-01-01 2019-01-31       7
1  2019-02-01 2019-02-28       4
2  2019-03-01 2019-03-31       8
3  2019-04-01 2019-04-30       5
4  2019-05-01 2019-05-31       7
5  2019-06-01 2019-06-30       3
6  2019-07-01 2019-07-31       7
7  2019-08-01 2019-08-31       8
8  2019-09-01 2019-09-30       5
9  2019-10-01 2019-10-31       4
10 2019-11-01 2019-11-30       8
11 2019-12-01 2019-12-31       8
```

And the report dates:

```
reports = pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-15', '2019-02-15', '2019-08-15'])
```

Using numpy's array broadcasting:

```
start = df['StartDate'].values
end = df['EndDate'].values
d = reports.values[:, None]
df[np.any((start <= d) & (d <= end), axis=0)]
```

Result:

```
   StartDate    EndDate  Volume
0 2019-01-01 2019-01-31       7
1 2019-02-01 2019-02-28       4
7 2019-08-01 2019-08-31       8
```

Comment: hi thanks for showing an example, what if i have irregular start and end date? (overlapping period which leads us to having more than one result? i.e. 1) start date 2019-1-1, enddate 2019-2-28, volume 4 then 2) start date 2019-1-1, enddate 2019-3-15, volume 4?   then i will get 4+4 = 8 if i look for dates between 2019-1-1 to 2019-2-28 , how does pandas deal with this one to many situation? thanks

Comment: In that case, all periods containing the report date will be selected. But each period will only be selected once, no matter how many report dates are in it.